# Kivy: Bring widget to front

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Images in *ActionBar* overlap *Toolbar*. (*Toolbar* is *[Bubble](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.bubble.html)* with *Label*)
My code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468909/how-to-make-tooltip-using-kivy/34471497#34471497) answer.

**Example for ActionBar button:**

```
TooltipButton:
    icon: 'images/32/quit.png'
    text: _('Quit')
    on_press: quit()
```

**TooltipButton class:**

```
class TooltipButton(ActionButton):
    tooltip = Tooltip()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(ActionButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        if not self.get_root_window():
            return
        pos = args[1]
        self.tooltip.pos = pos
        Clock.unschedule(self.display_tooltip)  # cancel scheduled event since I moved the cursor
        self.close_tooltip()  # close if it's opened
        if self.collide_point(*self.to_widget(*pos)):
            Clock.schedule_once(self.display_tooltip, 1)

    def close_tooltip(self, *args):
        self.remove_widget(self.tooltip)

    def display_tooltip(self, *args):
        self.tooltip.tip.text = self.text
        self.add_widget(self.tooltip)
```

**Tooltip rule *(superclass is Bubble)*:**

```
<Tooltip>:
    tip: tip
    Label:
        id: tip
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        text: 'Tip'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `add_widget()` and `remove_widget()` not from `self` (which is your `ActionButton`) but from an object that is higher in the hierarchy. You can store a reference to a parent of `ActionBar`  or just use `Window` object itself:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

# ...

class MyActionButton(ActionButton):
    # ...

    def close_tooltip(self, *args):
        Window.remove_widget(self.tooltip)

    def display_tooltip(self, *args):
        Window.add_widget(self.tooltip)
```

Note that this will probably change the computed size of your tooltip widget.

I updated referenced answer.

Comment: Size is very huge... I will use small statusbar.

Comment: In your tooltip replace `text_size: self.size` with two lines: `size_hint: None, None` and `size: self.texture_size`. I updated referenced answer again.