# How to animate a button on kivy when the cursor is over it?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm kinda new to Kivy and I was looking for a way to animate the button when the cursor is over it.

I've tried to manage a way to get the mouse position and compare it with the button coordinates but no success at all.

Comment: You really should post a [mcve], but have a look at the [mouse_pos](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=mouse_pos#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.mouse_pos) property of kivy `Windows`. You can bind a method to that property.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been (mostly) answered at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337947/highlight-a-kivy-togglebutton-with-mouse-hovering).There is a very nice example of this [here](https://gist.github.com/opqopq/15c707dc4cffc2b6455f) by Olivier POYEN under LGPL license. Basically he has defined a class called `HoverBehavior` that you should inherit from to make a new class, e.g. `HoverButton` or `HoverLabel` (as his example shows). Then you have access to the `on_enter` and `on_leave` functions, which you can use to change the button's image, or change a label's text color, or whatever you need.

To answer your exact question, I would seek to understand the `HoverBehavior` class, then copy/paste it from the source above, then make a new class like so:

```
class HoverButton(Button, HoverBehavior):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.background_normal = "some_image1.png" # Change the button's image when entered
    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.background_normal = "some_other_image.png" # Change image when leaving
```

**or** you could use the kv language which looks even cleaner:

```
<HoverButton>:
    background_normal: "some_image1.png" if self.hovered else "some_other_image.png"
```

just make sure you include a base class for the `HoverButton` in your python script if you use the 2nd option:

```
class HoverButton(Button, HoverBehavior):
    pass
```